# Django admin inline display but foreign key has opposite relation

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

```
class One(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    summary = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.summary


class Two(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Three(models.Model):



  one = models.ForeignKey(One, related_name='one_home')
    two = models.ForeignKey(Two, related_name='two_home')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tile
```

Now what i want is to show One and Two as inlines of Three in Django Admin.

I searched everywhere but inline display is given for opposite relationship. like where one has the foreign key of Three. not the other way round which i want.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to show One and Two as inlines of Three you will just have to move the relation ships to the other models. Is there any reason why these relationships are defined in model Three?

Comment: Yes models have to be like this as per my requirement... I dont wanna make changes on models

Comment: This doesn't seem possible in Django admin because when building `Three`, it needs to have an ID for `One` and `Two` before it can be saved. There's no way in Django admin to tell it "save One, then save Two, then save Three". It's going to try to save everything to the database with one SQL command. You'll have to change your model in order for it to work the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather simple:

Your model is "broken", three can have only 1 One and 1 Two.

you can have a list of three for both One an Two entities.

If you reverse the foreign keys, change the models they are on (both pointing @ Three)

```
class OneToThreeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fk_name = 'three'
    model = One

class TwoToThreeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    fk_name = 'three'
    model = Two
```