# Editing/Adding a Foreign Key object through inline display in the Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My Complete_Book model has a foreign key to Book. Book is something I'm using from an installed app (so, an 'outside app') I would like to be able to edit/create a 'Book' directly from the Complete_Book admin. Is this possible? I haven't been able to use inlines, as my foreign key relationship is 'backwards' from what inline allows.

My problem is the same as that explained in this question ([Django admin inline display but foreign key has opposite relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339809/django-admin-inline-display-but-foreign-key-has-opposite-relation)) but I cannot refactor my models as suggested in that answer. Is there any other way? Thank you for your help!

models.py

```
class Complete_Book(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey('topic')
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField()
    subprogram_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4)
```

Answer (score 9):

[django_reverse_admin](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin) is a django module to solve this problem of needing inlines where the relationships are the 'wrong' direction.

You'll need to add it to your requirements.txt and then import it:

admin.py

```
from django_reverse_admin import ReverseModelAdmin

class Complete_Book(ReverseModelAdmin):
    # usual admin stuff goes here
    inline_type = 'tabular'  # or could be 'stacked'
    inline_reverse = ['book']  # could do [('book', {'fields': ['title', 'authors'})] if you only wanted to show certain fields in the create admin

admin.site.register(Book, Complete_Book)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is actually quite easy. Just be sure to register a ModelAdmin for Book and admin will add a + button to the Complete_Book admin that will allow you to create a new Book.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear- I meant I want to be able to edit/add new Book info right there, in the same window. I don't want to click the '+' and then be taken to a new window...I want the Book fields (title, author, year) to appear right with the Complete_Book fields...?