# Django Admin, including reverse foreignkeyfields on page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following two models:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfields(max_lenght=500)
    (... more fields, but no foreignkeys to anyone)

class Ad(models.Model):
    seller = models.Foreignkey(Seller, related_name='ads')
    (... more fields that are not relevant to this question )
```

Now I want to include the Seller information on age 'Ad' page within the Django admin. I tried doing admin-inline like so:

```
class SellerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Seller
    view_on_site = False


class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['item', 'title', 'seller', 'price']
    list_filter = ('item', 'item_state', 'transaction_type', )
    view_on_site = False
    raw_id_fields = ('seller', 'searches')
    search_fields = ['title', 'seller__username']

    inlines = [
        SellerInline,
    ]
```

But this throws the following error:

```
<class 'scraper.admin.SellerInline'>: (admin.E202) 'scraper.Seller' has no ForeignKey to 'scraper.Ad'.
```

Now, some googling around informed me of the fact that reverse-relations dont work with the Inline admin. I could ofcourse reverse the foreignkey on the models. But each seller could potentially have hundreds of ads, (and the ad model has around 20 fields), which would lead to a very unwieldy seller page.

Does anyone know of a way to include the Seller fields on the Ad page within the admin, or is this really impossible?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513457/641249

Comment: Inline admins are exactly for reverse relations, but Ad to Seller is *not* a reverse relation, it is a forward one.